# I want \includegraphics{} to crop to the bounding box of an included PDF

Tags: graphics, bounding-box

Apparently, it's possible to use `gs` to automatically find the bounding box of a PDF. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962235/how-to-find-blank-page-in-pdf-file/11274720#11274720.

What I would like to do is to have a way of including a bunch of images such as the bounding box is scaled to the box in which I want the image to be shown.

Any thoughts on how to do that?

Comment: Just to be clear: Your included image has some surrounding white space that you want to automatically trim and insert into your document constrained to some fixed width and height? Why not just pre-process the (all) image(s) to have tight bounding boxes *before* you include them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of doing this using `\includegraphics{}`, I would suggest a workaround to achieve the desired goal. If you are running on Linux/CygWin you can do the following in command line prompt:

```
for i in *.pdf
do
  oname=`basename $i .pdf`-old.pdf
  mv $i $oname
  pdfcrop --margins 0 $oname $i
done
```

After doing this, all the PDFs that were already in the directory will be renamed to `*-old.pdf` and the newly generated PDFs will be cropped tightly without white margin. Then you can use these PDFs in the TeX file without any trim option in `\includegraphics{}`.

Comment: This method is as per Werner's comment.

Comment: Wow. That's great. I didn't know about `pdfcrop`. Thanks.

Comment: Ps - as an aside, `pdfgcrop` is a perl script that runs GhostScript

Comment: pdfcrop does not get the bounding box right, always, for me. Inkscape (command line/script) is still the only sure way I have found to correctly find the bounding box in an automated way, especially for text axis labels, and for whitespace beyond them.  It's ungainly, though.

Comment: I tried `pdfcrop`, it turned a 1MB PDF file into an 8MB PDF file.

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. I'm still getting a BoundingBox error :-(